# Select odd-number element only when in last position and not an only child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to target the last element if its odd.

Lets say I have 3 elements. I want to target the 3rd element only because its last and its odd. But if I have 1 element I dont want this rule to apply even if that in fact is odd count aswell.

```
1 2 3(target)

1 2 3 4 5(target)

1 2(don't target)

1(don't target)
```

How could I accomplish this?

So basicly I want to combine `:nth-child(odd)` and `:not(:only-child)` and only if that applies.

Answer (score 11):

I think you mean you want to select an element if it

- odd
- the last child
- not an only child

It is fairly simple to combine all this:

```
:nth-child(odd):last-child:not(:only-child) {
    color: blue; // or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to do this, with varying degrees of specificity in case it matters to you.

One, as already suggested by lonesomeday, with specificity (0, 3, 0) (3 pseudo-classes, with `:not(:only-child)` being equally specific to `:only-child`):

```
:nth-child(odd):last-child:not(:only-child)
```

Another, with specificity (0, 2, 0):

```
:nth-child(2n+3):last-child
```

The expression 2n+3 starts matching from the 3rd child onwards, eliminating the need for `:not(:only-child)`. (In comparison, the "odd" keyword is equivalent to 2n+1.)

Comment: Story checks out: Live Demo of BoltClock's answer: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpMYeP

Answer (score -2):

Should do the magic, you can use not, as selector

```
target:not(:first-child):last-child { /*some magic css*/ }
```

Comment: :nth-child(odd):last-child:not(:only-child) as the replier above you wrote. 
Thanks anyways!